# I need to have a mutable Array that has 8 interpolated strings in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I'm new to IOS and I'm not sure if I'm on the right track. What I need to know is if I'm on the right track and if I'm off it a hint on what to fix so I can get back on track. The mutable Array should read an array of speakers and say "`Hello, my name is <speakerArray>`" it should do that 8 times with a different name each time. This is what I Have:

```
- (NSArray*)badgesForSpeakers:(NSArray*)speakers {
    for(speakers i = 0; i => 7; i++)
    {
        NSString *greetings =@"Hello, my name is .";
        NSMutableArray *badges = [speakers arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:greetings];
    }

    return badges;
}
```

Comment: couple of things to change. the logical opertor is wrong use <. and use speakers.count. using constant value can create exception if u will use the speakers for reading.

Comment: this paricular code will never execute due to wrong condition also

Comment: third thing greetings is a string not array

Comment: what is speakers i = 0? . and for(i = 0; i => 7; i++) will never loop any, because condition  i => 7 always fail when i become from 0

Comment: What you want to do here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take this one step at a time. First of all, your operator in the loop is wrong; you mean to execute while `i` is *less* than or equal to 7. Thus, change `=>` to `<=`. However, it's more stylish to say `i < 8`. And finally, it's most stylish of all to use what's called "Fast Enumeration", which allows you to loop without an index at all. In fact, it will work no matter how many items are in your `speakers` array! That takes us here:

```
- (NSArray*)badgesForSpeakers:(NSArray*)speakers {
    for (NSString* speaker in speakers)
    {
        NSString *greetings =@"Hello, my name is .";
        NSMutableArray *badges = [speakers arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:greetings];
    }

    return badges;
}
```

Next, `greetings` isn't an array! It's a string. That's why calling `-arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:` doesn't make any sense, and why the compiler isn't going to like it. Let's make its name singular, `greeting`, to reflect this fact. **Strategy:** Your goal here is to create an empty array, then construct items one by one and add them to that array. That takes us to:

```
- (NSArray*)badgesForSpeakers:(NSArray*)speakers {
    NSMutableArray *badges = [NSMutableArray array]; //Here we make an empty array
    for (NSString* speaker in speakers)
    {
        NSString *greeting =@"Hello, my name is .";
        [badges addObject:greeting]; //Here we add one item to it each time 'round the loop
    }
    return badges;
}
```

Last, your string has no interpolation right now! It reads *literally* "Hello, my name is ." We do string interpolation using the `-stringWithFormat:` method.

**Finished Product:**

```
- (NSArray*)badgesForSpeakers:(NSArray*)speakers {
    NSMutableArray *badges = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString* speaker in speakers)
    {
        NSString *greeting = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello, my name is %@.",speaker];
        [badges addObject:greeting];
    }
    return badges;
}
```

That should get you started with fast enumeration and string interpolation. Remember to compile your code often and try to understand the compiler errors--it would have helped you with some of these issues.

Comment: Thanks. You really broke it down step by step and that was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean this

```
- (NSMutableArray *)badgesForSpeakers:(NSArray *)speakers {
    NSMutableArray *badges = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString *speaker in speakers) {
        [badges addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello, my name is %@", speaker]];
    }
    return badges;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

plz use this code

```
 - (NSArray*)badgesForSpeakers:(NSArray*)speakers {
       NSMutableArray *badges = [NSMutableArray alloc];
        for(int i = 0; i < speakers.count; i++)
        {
            NSString *greetings =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello, my name is .%@",[speakers objectAtIndex:i]];
            badges = [speakers addObject:greetings];
        }

        return [badges copy];
    }
```